# What is the effective NFC read bitrate using APDU commands?

Tags: android, performance, nfc

I am currently sending and receiving an accumulated 1628 bytes using the Android IsoDep.trancieve() function spread over 35 APDU commands (select application, authenticate, read). The bytecount includes returned MAC checksums and result codes as returned by transcieve().

This communication takes 580ms. As these bytes are sent and received half duplex i calculate the effective bitrate to ~220kbit/s.

The Android NFC stack supports 424kbit/s NFC communication, and according to [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_field_communication) uses 10% modulation (=protocol overhead?)

Do I have a performance problem, or is ~50% effective NFC protocol overhead acceptable?

EDIT: One explanation could be that the card itself has limited processing power. See my question regarding this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33781600/nfc-apdu-read-command-performance-tuning)

Comment: I would remove the select application and authentication part from the benchmark. Did you try the plain data transfer variant for a comparison?